# How to increment a variable in PostgreSQL UPDATE statement

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.3

I want to add e-mails numbered from 1 to 100. So effectively I want to do something like:

```
tmp := 0
update user SET tmp = tmp + 1, email = 'test' || TO_CHAR(tmp,'fm00000') || '@example.com'
    where removed = false
    ORDER BY id
    limit 100;
```

And preferably would like it to work in 8.3. Note - I cannot use ids as they are not from 1 to 100 in the selected rows.

Edit: Forgot I'm on 8.3...

Comment: if you want to ADD values, you must use `INSERT`, not `UPDATE`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. I got it crossed over with the other question about (name, id) counters.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a hack with variables in Postgres. Just use a window function. Unfortunately window functions cannot be used directly in an `UPDATE` statement, but this can easily be combined with a CTE:

```
with numbered_users as (
   select id, 
          row_number() over (order by email) as rn
   from users
   where removed = false
) 
update users 
  set email = 'test' || TO_CHAR(nu.rn,'fm00000') || '@example.com'
from numbered_users nu
where rmoved = false
  and users.id = nu.id;
```

This assumes the `id` column is unique

Comment: I guess that would work, but I could not update to 8.4 and stuck on 8.3 on that server... But `create temp sequence tmp;` Works fine :-).

Comment: @Nux: you should have mentioned that you are using an outdated and un-supported version. Plus: you shouldn't upgrade to 8.4 either - that is also end-of-life. _If_ you upgrade go straight to 9.3 (or even 9.4 depending on when you do it)

Comment: Unfortunately they broke compatibility on 8.4 and I was not able to upgrade because of one old application. I'm aware that 8.x is not supported. Thanks for your effort anyway.

Comment: @Nux: they didn't "break compatibility" in 8.4. They just enforced some rules more strictly than before. All the casts that were removed in 8.4 have always been discouraged in earlier releases. Plus: relying on implicit data type conversion (which is what you did when your code breaks with 8.4) is bad coding style *any* DBMS not just Postgres.